# Setting conditional javascript for web form dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

I have a web form that I'm applying both client and server side validation to and on this one text input field I'm looking for some way to have conditional code that sets a character limit based on what a dropdown menu is set to.

For example:

If Option 3 is selected, limit maximum character limit to 10.

```
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option> Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
</select>

<label>Text Field</label>
<input type="text" />
```

I've been experimenting with a number of pre-coded javascript / jquery validation scripts and they all work fine except when it comes to this particular need.

How can this be done?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a select onchange event that will set the maxLength of the input. You can use the option value as the value for the event. Example:

```
<select id="sel" onchange="document.getElementById('txt').maxLength = document.getElementById('sel').value;" >
<option value="3">Option 1</option>
<option value="5"> Option 2</option>
<option value="10">Option 3</option>
<option value="20">Option 4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<label>Text Field</label>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="" maxlength="3" />
```

You can test it here - http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/R7RtJ/

Comment: The problem is that he probably needs to, on the server-side, actually do something based on the dropdown...

Comment: I'd change the max length based on either the value of the option, or whether the selected index is 3:

`document.getElementById('txt').maxLength=(this.value=="10")?3:null;`
`document.getElementById("txt").maxLength=(this.selectedIndex==2)?3:null;`